# Limit involving square roots, more than two "rooted" terms

Tags: limits

The limit is
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+5x-2}-\sqrt{4x^2-3x+7}+\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}\right)$$
which has a value of $\dfrac{27}{4}$.

Normally, I would know how to approach a limit of the form
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left( \sqrt{a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1}\pm\sqrt{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}\right)$$
(provided it exists) by using the expression's conjugate, but this problem has me stumped.

I've considered using the conjugate
$$\sqrt{x^2+5x-2}-\sqrt{4x^2-3x+7}-\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}$$
and a term like this one,
$$\sqrt{x^2+5x-2}+\sqrt{4x^2-3x+7}-\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}$$
but that didn't seem to help simplify anything.

**Edit:** I stumbled across something at the last second that lets me use the conjugate approach. The expression can be rewritten as
$$\sqrt{x^2+5x-2}-\sqrt{4x^2-3x+7}+\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}\\
\sqrt{x^2+5x-2}-2\sqrt{x^2-\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{7}{4}}+\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}\\
\left(\sqrt{x^2+5x-2}-\sqrt{x^2-\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{7}{4}}\right)+\left(\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}-\sqrt{x^2-\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{7}{4}}\right)$$
which approaches
$$\frac{23}{8}+\frac{31}{8}=\frac{27}{4}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it as:

$$\left(\sqrt{x^2+5x-2} - \left(x+\frac{5}{2}\right)\right) -\\ \left(\sqrt{4x^2-3x+7}-\left(2x-\frac{3}{4}
\right)\right) +\\
\left(\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}-\left(x+\frac{7}{2}\right)\right)+\left(\frac{5}{2}+\frac 34+\frac{7}2\right)$$

Or something like that. Each of the first three terms has limit zero...

Comment: Did you complete the square along the way to get those linear terms?

Comment: Yes. Basically, $x^2+5x-2=(x+\frac{5}{2})^2 - C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: I like the approach, but this gives me an answer of $\dfrac{21}{4}$.

Comment: Yeah, I had a sense that I got signs wrong somewhere - that was why I wrote "Or something like that." The idea is the important thing :)

Comment: Yeah, It should be $+\frac{3}{4}$, not $-\frac{3}4$, which gives you $\frac{27}{4}$.

Comment: Alright, that fixes everything! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+5x-2}-\sqrt{4x^2-3x+7}+\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}\right) = 27/4 $

i will use the binomial theorem in the form 
$(BIG + small)^{1/2} = BIG^{1/2} + {1 \over 2}BIG^{-1/2}small+\cdots $  to each.

$$\sqrt{x^2+5x-2} = x + {5x - 2 \over 2x} + \cdots \\
-\sqrt{4x^2-3x+7} = -\left( 2x  + {-3x + 7 \over 4x} + \cdots \right) \\
\sqrt{x^2+7x+5} = x + {7x + 5 \over 2x} + \cdots \\
$$

adding the dominant terms the limit is $${5 \over 2} + {3 \over 4} + {7 \over 2} = {10 + 3 + 14\over 4} = {27 \over 4} $$

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Taylor series. Start writing $$A=\sqrt{x^2+5x-2}-\sqrt{4x^2-3x+7}+\sqrt{x^2+7x+5}$$ $$\frac Ax=\sqrt{1+\frac{5x-2}{x^2}}-2\sqrt{1-\frac{3x-7}{4x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{7x+5}{x^2}}$$ Now, remember that, when $y$ is small compared to $1$, $\sqrt{1+y}=1+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}+O\left(y^3\right)$.

So replace $y$ by $\frac{5x-2}{x^2}$ for the first radical, by $-\frac{3x-7}{4x^2}$ for the second radical and by $\frac{7x+5}{x^2}$ for the third radical. So, in the order, each radical write $$\sqrt{1+\frac{5x-2}{x^2}}=1+\frac{5}{2 x}-\frac{33}{8 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)$$ $$\sqrt{1-\frac{3x-7}{4x^2}}=1-\frac{3}{8 x}+\frac{103}{128 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)$$ $$\sqrt{1+\frac{7x+5}{x^2}}=1+\frac{7}{2 x}-\frac{29}{8 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)$$ All of the above makes $$\frac Ax=\frac{27}{4 x}-\frac{599}{64 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)$$ that is to say $$A=\frac{27}{4}-\frac{599}{64 x}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\right)$$ which gives  the limit but also tells how it is approched.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} = \dfrac{\sqrt{a+\dfrac{b}{x}+\dfrac{c}{x^2}}}{\dfrac{1}{x}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{a+by+cy^2}}{y}$,and use L'hospitale rule. Note $y  \to 0$. Repeat this process for each term of the sum and simplify to a common fraction and proceed to L'hospitale rule.

Comment: How am I able to use L'Hopital's rule if $a\not=0$? Shouldn't I have the form $\dfrac{0}{0}$ in order to apply it?